# local type field access cannot be used in an evaluation expression

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When I am debugging using Eclipse, I am trying to inspect a Set s:

```
for (Object object: s)
                {
                 //Code
                }
```

But, it instead gives me following message:

"local type field access cannot be used in an evaluation expression".

What is the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us the code in the for loop?

Comment: Code inside and inclusive for loop:

for (Object object: s)
                {
                 S s = (S) object;
                }

Comment: Google sends us to a known issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=278146

Comment: @Andreas_D, I have seen that. But, what might be the reason for this?

Comment: Looking at this bug I can't reproduce it. I'm using Eclipse Juno (Eclipse Java Development Tools - 3.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate local variable 's'. Better to avoid casting by doing:

```
Set<MyType> mySet = new HashSet<MyType>();
// populate mySet

for (MyType myType: mySet) { 
    // do work with myType
}
```